# Not all items in ListView shown Android

Tags: android, firebase, listview

I'm developing an application where I have certain items in a ListView. The problem is that not all items are showing. Two of them are missing even though the list scrolls.

The items are collected from firebase, and therefore the code is inside a ValueEventListener.

Here is my fragment where the list is shown:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="kandidat.trainingapp.Fragments.FavoritesFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/favorite_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:dividerHeight="3dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Code where a the items are added to the adapter:

```
 FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("favorites");
    DatabaseReference myRef = ref.child(user.getUid());

    DatabaseReference pointRef = db.getReference("users").child(user.getUid()).child("points");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favorite_list);

    LayoutInflater inflateheader = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflateheader.inflate(R.layout.layout_favorites_header, listView,false);


    listView.addHeaderView(header);

    ArrayList<FavoriteModel> allFavoriteItems = new ArrayList<>();

        myRef.orderByChild("favorites").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                String busStops = "Walked bus stops";
                Set<FavoriteModel> bus = new TreeSet<>();
                String stairs = "Walked flight of stairs";
                Set<FavoriteModel> stairsList = new TreeSet<>();
                String stand = "Minutes standing up";
                Set<FavoriteModel> standList = new TreeSet<>();

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("BusStop").getChildren()) {
                    Integer dsVal = (int) (long) ds.getValue();
                    bus.add(new FavoriteModel(busStops, dsVal));

                }
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("Stairs").getChildren()) {
                    Integer dsVal = (int) (long) ds.getValue();
                    stairsList.add(new FavoriteModel(stairs, dsVal));

                }
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("standing").getChildren()) {
                    Integer dsVal = (int) (long) ds.getValue();
                    standList.add(new FavoriteModel(stand, dsVal));

                }

                allFavoriteItems.clear();
                allFavoriteItems.addAll(bus);
                allFavoriteItems.addAll(stairsList);
                allFavoriteItems.addAll(standList);




                FavoriteAdapter mAdapter = new FavoriteAdapter(context,
                        R.layout.layout_favorite_row, R.id.activity_text, allFavoriteItems);
                if(allFavoriteItems.isEmpty()){
                    if(isAdded()) {
                        emptyText = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.empty_favorites);
                        emptyText.setText(getString(R.string.empty_favorites_string));
                    }
                }else{
                    if(isAdded()) {
                        emptyText = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.empty_favorites);
                        emptyText.setText(getString(R.string.explain_favorites));
                    }

                }



                listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);






            }
```

I hope anyone knows what's wrong. Please tell me if more information or code is needed.

Comment: I would start with removing the FrameLayout. Possibly even the LinearLayout. You only need a ListView xml element if that's all you want to show

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for fast response. Removed both Layouts but it still does not show all my items

Comment: Problem solved! The listview was covered by the bottom navigation bar. Added:                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/navigation_bar_height"

And now it works!

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer below rather than leave that in the comments.